# Triggering a Elementor Pop up

Tags: php, if-statement, popup, elementor

I am trying to display an Elementor pop up based on the if-else condition from function.php in WordPress. Below is the code snippet of the if-else condition.

So instead of displaying the HTML banner, I am trying to display a pop-up created in Elementor.

````
if($_GET['id'] == "****"){

           echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="4; url=******" />';
       }
   
 echo '<div class="mm_success_alert">The condition is true</div>';   
       
   }else{
       
       echo '<div class="mm_danger_alert">The condition is false</div>';
  //echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=*******" />';
   }
   
  
}```
````

Comment: I tried using the below statement, but it did not seem to work 

`elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: 123 } )`;

Comment: there are two closing parenthesis '}'  in IF condition whereas only one opening parenthesis

Comment: The if-else condition is working fine. I am looking for a solution to trigger the popup and not the HTML banner.

Comment: based on your code snippet IF condition shouldn't be working

Comment: Please clarify what error do you get, and other possible debugging details.